# Implement Python Numpy Array operations mod 2, use booleans or int 0/1 mod 2?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, integer, matrix-multiplication

I'm looking to do work with Numpy arrays using integer arithmetic mod 2. Is there any advantage to working with booleans rather than 0/1 int data types? I tried to look up the data types and from what found both data types would require a byte of storage for each entry in the array. Is that right? Is the performance speed and memory usage any different in using these two implementations?

I need to do matrix addition mod 2 (XOR for booleans), element wise multiplication (AND), possibly standard matrix multiplication mod 2, and negation (which could just be NOT with booleans and addition mod 2 with an all ones matrix). Thanks.

Comment: If you use the correct datatype (e.g. `np.int8`) then both would only take 1 byte per value.

Comment: @sj95126 Thanks. Do you know at all about any differences in computation speed?